# how to validate a phone number in nestjs-graphQL

Tags: graphql, nestjs

Nest.js

```
import { Field, InputType } from '@nestjs/graphql';
@InputType()
export class SignUpInput {
  @Field()
  phone: string;

}
```

how to validate a phone number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `class-validator` for this:

```
import { InputType, Field } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { IsPhoneNumber } from 'class-validator';

@InputType()
export class SignUpInput {
  @Field()
  @IsPhoneNumber()
  phone: string;
}
```

To enable class validation in NestJS, please, read official [docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation).

Follow [this](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator) to read more about about `class-validator` decorators.